# Split and transpose bi-dimensional array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Is there a way to transpose sets of data from an array?

For example: I have a 2D array of 1000 rows and 1 column. I want to split it in a way that I have 40 arrays of 25 rows and 1 column. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to write this yourself, either by dumping it into collections and then using the stream API or by using some for loops.

For example to split a 1d array of integers into a 2d array:

```
int SPLIT_SIZE = 40;

for (int i=0;i<src.length()/SPLIT_SIZE;i++) {
   dest[i]=new int[SPLIT_SIZE];
   for (int j=0;j<SPLIT_SIZE;j++) {
      dest[i][j] = src[i*SPLIT_SIZE+j];
   }

}
```

Build on this for the correct split you need and to cope with the extra dimensions etc as you need.